# Why are weapons pylon fittings usually tension fittings?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, aircraft-structures

As far as I see, most of the fighter jet pylon fittings are tension fitting instead of the shear fitting. What is the logic behind that?

Comment: Might be because they need to be jettison-able.

Comment: Please define what you mean by tension vs shear. Wing pylons on the F-16, for instance, are held on with 3 bolts. 2 front one rear. They are NOT jettisonable.